# Rviz crash with exception raised by qt.qpa.screen

Tags: rviz, ros-melodic, roslaunch, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's a really weird problem. When I'm trying to launch my launch file using the terminal embedded in **VIsual Studio Code**, I got an error called ***"qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
Could not connect to any X display."*** But rviz seems totally OK while using the vanilla terminal.

Part of my launch file is shown below:

```
<launch>
    <node type="rviz" name="rviz" pkg="rviz" args=" $(find detect_core)/rviz/config.rviz" />
    <node pkg="detect_core" type="detect_core_node" name="detect_core_node" output="screen"/>
</launch>
```

When I launch this file in VSCode, it shows the following message while all the other processes works normally:

> ```
> qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display  Could not connect to any X display.
> ```

```
[rviz-4] process has died [pid 2702, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/melodic/lib/rviz/rviz
/home/hcd/ROS_LiDAR/src/LiDAR/detect_core/rviz/config.rviz
__name:=rviz __log:=/home/hcd/.ros/log/053e51c0-f088-11e9-91c8-d0abd582c8c3/rviz-4.log].
log file:
/home/hcd/.ros/log/053e51c0-f088-11e9-91c8-d0abd582c8c3/rviz-4*.log
```

But when I launch rviz directly from terminal, it works perfectly fine.

```
(base) <font color="#8AE234"><b>hcd@hcd-PC</b></font>:<font color="#729FCF"><b>~</b></font>$ rviz
[ INFO] [1571281807.940736481]: rviz version 1.13.4
[ INFO] [1571281807.940797989]: compiled against Qt version 5.9.5
[ INFO] [1571281807.940823596]: compiled against OGRE version 1.9.0 (Ghadamon)
[ INFO] [1571281807.944071605]: Forcing OpenGl version 0.
[ INFO] [1571281808.422031984]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ INFO] [1571281808.422139032]: OpenGl version: 4.6 (GLSL 4.6).
```

Thank you for your help~~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/335550/rviz-crash-with-exception-raised-by-qt.qpa.screen/) by [CH_YZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/47302/ch_yz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-10-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems like it that for some reason `rviz` cannot contact the X server from "within" your VSCode terminal.

Could be that the `DISPLAY` environment variable isn't set, or some other bit of configuration is missing.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CH_YZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/47302/ch_yz/) on 2019-10-17**:
Yes, I've just solved this problem simply by setting the correct DISPLAY environment variable. Many thanks for your comment~~